# Save data from a texbox in an array (vector)

Tags: c#

I have the following question: How could I save what is in a texbox with numbers, separated from each other by commas, which are entered by the user in an array (vector)? The maximum number of numbers that can be entered is 3, and separated by commas, since I need to make a cross product of vectors (Product point). In advance thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use "split" and it will create the array.

```
var arrayList = yourTexbox.Text.split(",");
```

Comment: I had never used Split, could you give me a more detailed example please, I am a beginner, I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem, is just a method that will split your string by the char given, in this case ',' check this doc is very well explained https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/split-string-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Yeah, but you might also have to trim each element and convert them to int and handle possible exceptions.

Comment: So, with the previous instruction, I already get the array, right? but, I need it of type int so that it works

Comment: Yes you get the array, and you can access it from the index, like "arrayList[i]", but as  Hirasawa Yui said if is an user input you should first trim it, and do some data validation, then you should tryparse the values.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for  Hirasawa Yui

Comment: Effectively it is information that is entered by the user, the project I have it in a windows form. So how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Give textboxes name like txt[1], txt[2], txt[3] and receive that from backend as array which contains value of textbox1 in 1th index , textbox2 in 2nd index etc

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.Matches with a pattern that only matches sets of 3